# jquery menu - active links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a jquery menu that when I click on one of the links (with reloading the page), it changes its class to "active" and removes this class when I click on another link.

here is my code :

enter code here`$(document).ready(function(){

```
$(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('inny').siblings().removeClass('inny');
  });
});
});




 <ul id="mainMenu">
        <li class="hover-width1"><a href="d.html">STRONA GŁÓWNA</a></li>
        <li class="hover-width3"><a href="glowna.html">OFERTA</a></li>
        <li class="hover-width3"><a href="d2.html">CENNIK</a></li>
        <li class="hover-width2"><a href="tom.html">PRZEPISY</a></li>
        <li class="hover-width2"><a href="jan.html">GALERIA</a></li>
        <li class="hover-width1"><a href="#">NASI KLIENCI</a></li>
        <li class="hover-width2"><a href="#">NARZĘDZIA</a></li>
        <li class="hover-width1"><a href="#">CIEKAWOSTKI</a></li>
        <li class="hover-width2"><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Can someone tell me why my code is not working when I reload the page:(

Comment: what do you mean by "when I reload the page"?

Comment: This mean: When I click for any link

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(document).ready(function(){` or `$(function(){` to init jquery code, but not both at the same time.

```
$(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('inny').siblings().removeClass('inny');
  });
});
```

The code should work fine, and when you reload the page the markup changes won't stay up, so you must make use of the uri / cookies to determine what item to show active.

Comment: Please tell me what can I do it?